# Date differences in php

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to get the differences, in days, between two dates.  The first date is the current day.  The other date is their bday.  I want to calculate the difference between today, and their next bday.  Currently, it outputs correctly if the user types in their bday as today, but anything else just messes up.  I'd like to calculate it by days.

For example, if I enter my bday as `01/11/1988` for example, my program will output `0 Years, 1 Months, 21 Days`.  If I can get it to correctly output the years, months, and days, then I can calculate the total number of days, but as of right now it is just not working properly.  Thanks for taking a look.  Here is my code:

```
if (isset($_POST["birthday"])){
    $birthday=$_POST["birthday"];
    if (!empty($birthday)){
        $birthdayArray = explode("/", $birthday);
        if (count($birthdayArray) != 3  || strlen($birthday) != 10){
            echo "<b>Please follow the format (ex. 09/15/1988).</b><br/>";
            }else{
                $month = $birthdayArray[0];
                $day = $birthdayArray[1];
                $year = $birthdayArray[2];
                echo "Your bday is: ".$month."/".$day."/".$year;
                echo "<br/>";
                if (strcmp($currentMonth,$month) == 0 && strcmp($currentDay,$day) == 0){
                    echo "Your birthday is today.<br/>";
                }else{
                    $date1 = new DateTime("$currentYear-$currentMonth-$currentDay");
                    if (strcmp($currentMonth, $month) <= 0 && strcmp($currentDay, $day) < 0 ){
                        $currentYear = $currentYear + 1;
                        $date2 = new DateTime("$currentYear-$month-$day");
                    }else{
                        $date2 = new DateTime("$currentYear-$month-$day");
                    }
                    $interval = $date1->diff($date2);
                    echo $interval->y." Years, ".$interval->m." Months, ".$interval->d." Days.";

                }
            }
    }else{
        echo "<b>Please enter your birthday.</b><br/>";
    }
}
```

Comment: This calls for basic debugging. At which point do things go wrong? What do test outputs e.g. of `month`, `day`, and `year` show?

Comment: They show whatever the date the user enters, for example if I enter 09/15/1988, then $month would be 09, $day would be 15, and $year would be 1988.

Comment: Okay, then debug it further. Do test outputs of every value after every operations. At which point does it go off the rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if (strcmp($currentMonth, $month) <= 0 && strcmp($currentDay, $day) < 0 ){
            $currentYear = $currentYear + 1;
```

what this condition actually doing ?

If current month is less than birthday month , you are increasing the current year. But you should do in reverse manner.

May be you to tried to implement this :

```
  //assume BIRTHDAY : 03/24/1990    
 if(...)
    echo "today birthday ";
  else  
  {
   if(currentMonth > $month) // may be today : 04/21/2012
   {
     $currentYear++;
   }
   else if(currentMonth == $month) // may be today : 03/29/2012
   {
    if($currentDay > $day) // may be today : 03/29/2012
     {  $currentYear++; }
   }
  } 
  $date2 = new DateTime("$currentYear-$month-$day");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this code, Its giving out as you wish.

```
    if (isset($_POST["birthday"])){
    $birthday=$_POST["birthday"];
    if (!empty($birthday)){
        $birthdayArray = explode("/", $birthday);
        if (count($birthdayArray) != 3  || strlen($birthday) != 10){
            echo "<b>Please follow the format (ex. 09/15/1988).</b><br/>";
            }else{
                $month = $birthdayArray[0];
                $day = $birthdayArray[1];
                $year = $birthdayArray[2];
                $currentMonth = date('m');
                $currentDay = date('d');
                $currentYear = date('Y');
                echo "Your bday is: ".$month."/".$day."/".$year;
                echo "<br/>";
                if (strcmp($currentMonth,$month) == 0 && strcmp($currentDay,$day) == 0){
                    echo "Your birthday is today.<br/>";
                }else{
                    $date1 = new DateTime("$currentYear-$currentMonth-$currentDay");
                    if (strcmp($currentMonth, $month) <= 0 && strcmp($currentDay, $day) < 0 ){
                        $currentYear = $currentYear + 1;
                        $date2 = new DateTime("$currentYear-$month-$day");
                    }else{
                        $date2 = new DateTime("$currentYear-$month-$day");
                    }
                    $interval = $date1->diff($date2);
                    echo $interval->y." Years, ".$interval->m." Months, ".$interval->d." Days.";

                }
            }
    }else{
        echo "<b>Please enter your birthday.</b><br/>";
    }
}
```